# On Edit button click i am getting duplicate textbox for DOB field in my Angular 6 application

Tags: html, css, angular

[image]

I have an issue on Edit button click in my modal page, once the record is submitted successfully i see this issue, can some one review my code and let me know the issue to fix this.

```
 <div class="col-3">
          <input class="form-control" type="search" name="DateOfBirth" [(ngModel)]="hldr.DateOfBirth" [hidden]="selRowData.actionmode==='ADD'"
            disabled>
          <div class="input-group" daterangepicker [options]="singlePicker" (selected)="singleSelect($event,hldr,'DateOfBirth')" [hidden]="selRowData.actionmode==='VIEW'">
            <input class="form-control" type="search" name="DateOfBirth" [(ngModel)]="hldr.DateOfBirth" maxlength="10">
            <div class="input-group-append" style="cursor:pointer">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.input-group {
   margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Chan you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: I am new to that, if you don't mind can you let me know here?

Comment: Add your code here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xssnqq

Comment: go to https://stackblitz.com/ and click Angular workspace, and then add required code there

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy to spot the problem, difficult to share the solution due to incomplete information.

```
[hidden]="selRowData.actionmode==='ADD'"

[hidden]="selRowData.actionmode==='VIEW'"
```

When your component is initiated, the action mode has a value and its most likely view.

Your problem is that after edit,  it's neither view not add.